# Pweave resulting in MultipleInstanceError after updating anaconda

Tags: python, pweave

After updating to the current version of Anacondo (Anaconda3-5.0.0-Windows-x86_64), my pweave code has run into some issues.

When running for example

```
pweave.weave('example.texw', doctype = 'tex')
```

I get the MultipleInstanceError with the traceback shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-9-85475eedd74e>", line 1, in <module>
pweave.weave('example.texw', doctype = 'tex')
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site
packages\pweave\__init__.py", line 59, in weave
doc.weave()
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\pweave\pweb.py", line 192, in weave
self.run()
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site 
packages\pweave\pweb.py", line 127, in run
self.wd
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site
packages\pweave\processors\jupyter.py", line 169, in __init__
super(IPythonProcessor, self).__init__(*args, embed_kernel=embed)
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site
packages\pweave\processors\jupyter.py", line 34, in __init__
km.start_kernel(cwd=path, stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site
packages\ipykernel\inprocess\manager.py", line 46, in start_kernel
self.kernel = InProcessKernel(parent=self, session=self.session)
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site 
packages\ipykernel\inprocess\ipkernel.py", line 72, in __init__
super(InProcessKernel, self).__init__(**traits)
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site 
packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 46, in __init__
kernel      = self,
File "C:\Users\tdecloedt\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site
packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 423, in instance
'%s are being created.' % cls.__name__

MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances
InProcessInteractiveShell are being created.
```

I can however run pweave from the terminal as

```
pweave -f tex example.texw
```

I have not found relevant answers regarding the MultipleInstanceError elsewhere. 
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem